# Best and short way to run a program if another is not installed

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I have this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

num=${1:-undefined}
cmd=$(which {banner,echo} | head -n1)

until [[ "$num" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; do 
    read -p "Type a number: " num
done

for ((num;num>=0;num--)); do
   $cmd $num
   sleep 1
done
```

But I think that there is a better way to know if a program is installed. I've tried these. However I think that are unclear:

1. `which banner && cmd=banner || cmd=echo`
2. `cmd=$(eval 'which '{banner,echo}'||' :)`
3. `cmd=$(which {banner,echo} | head -n1)`
4. `cmd=$(which banner || which echo)`

I like 3 more than the rest, however I think that someone could help me to find a good method to do this. I accept the use of `type`, `hash` or `command` instead if needed.

This is a compact code challenge, so I want to make a oneliner, make it short, and try to not repeat the variable name or any command (except `||`, `&&` and so)

Comment: Please take a look [here at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script)

Comment: @FloHimself: I want to assign the command to the variable in the same line.

Comment: `hash banner 2>/dev/null && COMMAND=banner || COMMAND=echo`

Comment: Your comment is so similar to the option 1 (`which banner && COMMAND=banner || COMMAND=echo`)

Comment: Why do you want it in one line anyway? What's wrong to use a function `my_banner` with a simple `if`?

Comment: Code size and readability.

Comment: @Helio; why do you think, seriously, that readability and code size would be factors in a function based approach? YMMV, but expanding variables is certainly not clearer than a function/command call, rather the opposite is true; `banner` and `echo` are also commands.

Comment: Using `which {a,b} | head -1` is a clever trick. I doubt you'll get it any shorter than that. As a general rule though, you want to avoid UPPER CASE variable names in shell scripts since environmental variables are upper case and that can be confusing or lead to errors if you happen to use on of the shell's reserved words as a variable name.

Comment: @terdon: And what about doing this to use the bash builtin `echo` and not `/bin/echo`? `command=$(which {banner,echo} | head -1 | xargs basename)`

Comment: This is even shorter: `command=basename $(which {banner,echo} | head -1))` or even `command=basename ``$(which {banner,echo} | head -1))``

Comment: @terdon: I thought it, but the `xargs` version looks more readable, no?

Comment: @Helio I can't understand if you prefer short or readable. You can't have both.

Comment: Your [comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196690/best-and-short-way-to-run-a-program-if-another-is-not-installed?noredirect=1#comment330081_196690) throws syntax error. Did you meant ```command=`basename $(which {banner,echo} | head -1)` ```? You can escape a backtick putting the code between two or more (i.e. ```` ``my code`` ````)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function-based approach results in the clearest code. There's at least two variants possible, the one suggested by FloHimself above in the comment (which would not be my preferred way):

```
function myprint
{
    if type banner >/dev/null
    then  banner "$@"
    else  echo "$@"
    fi
}

myprint "Hello World!"
```

or - the variant I'd prefer - to use a **conditional function definition**:

```
if type banner >/dev/null
then  function myprint { banner "$@" ;}
else  function myprint { echo "$@" ;}
fi

myprint "Hello World!"
```

which doesn't have the overhead of an `if`-condition with each call, and which also does not require duplication of string or variable expressions (as in another suggestion).

Comment: @terdon; thanks for the edit. (I had just copied the OP's method, but of course `type` should be used.)

Comment: The second way is very good (although, not as good as I would like)

Comment: @Helio; thanks for the appreciation; but what's missing to be liked by you?

Comment: Many lines. I'm searching for a clever, shorter, minimally readable, oneliner (if possible) and POSIX **in**compatible. A example is the number 3 of my original post.

Comment: @Helio; You know that you have to write the conditional declaration just **once** in your code, and the many lines where you use it are as terse as possible. - You should also not forget the safety and extensibility argument; any string expansion approach is inferior in tha respect. - But it's your choice, of course. Just don't expect you'll find something better. :-) (Note that you can put the conditional also in one line.)

Comment: @Helio; Note that you can use POSIX complient function definitions as well, if that's what you're missing. Just write `myprint()`. (Note that your edited version of the question is not POSIX complient.)

Comment: Yes, I know.  Your answer is the best until now. I prefer your answer as is than as a oneliner.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is to just run

```
command1 "hello world" || command2 "hello world"
```

If the first command doesn't exist, the left hand side of the `||` wil fail so the command on the right will be run. I don't see why you need to test first. Just do, and if you fail, do something else.

You can make that slightly better by ignoring error messages caused by a missing command and avoiding the repetition of the string:

```
string="Hello world!"
banner "$string" || echo "$string"
```

---

If you really need to check for the existence of a command, I would do it like this:

```
command="banner"
type "$command"  2>/dev/null || command="echo"
"$command" "Hello world!"
```

Comment: How do I avoid the "command not found" message?

Comment: @Helio that's what the `2>/dev/null` does.

Comment: In the first solution (on the above part) I don't see any redirection. I refered to the above solution.

Comment: @Helio you can add the redirection to the first one as well: `command1 "hello world" 2>/dev/null || command2 "hello world"` .

Comment: Sincerely, I don't like that, I tried this: `function myprint() {  eval {banner,echo}' "hello world" 2>/dev/null ||' :; }` It works, but is so long.

Comment: @Helio why are you making it that complex? Why not just `( s="Hello world!"; banner "$s" || echo "$s" ) 2>/dev/null` ?

Comment: I'll update the question with the entire code.

Comment: How could you do something like this `alias cat=$(hightlight || cat)`. So that if I have hightlight installed should use it, if not fallback to cat

Comment: @aemonge please post a separate question for that, explaining what kind of input `highlight` takes and what exactly you need.

Answer (score 0):

In `zsh`, where the `$commands` special associative array maps commands to their path, you can do something like:

```
cmd=${commands[figlet]-${commands[banner]-echo}}
```

For `$cmd` to be set to the path of the `figlet` utility if it exists, or to that of `banner` otherwise or to `echo` (a builtin) if neither `figlet` nor `banner` exist.

Instead of a variable (`$cmd`), you could define a command instead:

```
hash cmd=${commands[figlet]-${commands[banner]-$commands[echo]}}
```

though here you'd end up with the standalone `echo` utility instead of the builtin one. Also beware that that hashed command would disappear upon `hash -r` aka `rehash`.